# Riemann Sum in 2D: How to define area cells used in integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Does anyone know how to define the two dimensional area cells (Cartesian Product) for the 2D [Riemann Sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)?

The sum in two dimensions with domain $A$ is defined on Wiki as:

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x^*_i, y^*_i) \Delta A_i
$$

where $(x^*_i, y^*_i) \in A_i$

I thought of the following, but think it's either over complicated or wrong:
$$
I_0 = inf(\{x | (x,y) \in A\})
$$
$$
I_1 = inf(\{y | (x,y) \in A\})
$$
$$
l_{\alpha} = I_0 - sup(\{x | (x,y) \in A\})
$$
$$
l_{\beta} = I_1 - sup(\{y | (x,y) \in A\})
$$
$$
P_0 = \frac {l_{\alpha}} n, P_1 = \frac {l_{\beta}} n
$$
$$
A_i = \{(x,y) | (I_0 + P_0 mod(i-1, n) \le x \le I_0 + P_0 mod(i, n)) \land (I_1 + P_1 mod(i-1, n) \le y \le I_1 + P_1 mod(i, n)) \}
$$